# Docker for windows: Error creating machine

Tags: windows, docker, hyper-v, docker-machine

Simply following directions here: https://docs.docker.com/machine/drivers/hyper-v/

Tried this command to create a new virtual machine

```
$ docker-machine create --driver hyperv vm
```

But don't get too far and get this error

```
Running pre-create checks...
Creating machine...
(vm) Copying C:\Users\vostro\.docker\machine\cache\boot2docker.iso to C:\Users\
(vm) Creating SSH key...
(vm) Creating VM...
(vm) Using switch "DockerNAT"
(vm) Creating VHD
(vm) Starting VM...
Error creating machine: Error in driver during machine creation: exit status 1
```

The documentation makes it seem simple to set up a VM, but I can't find any troubleshooting help when I get to this point.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: Nope. Went a different, unrelated route

Comment: OK, thanks for getting back to me.