# Can't create Docker machine

Tags: windows, docker, hyper-v

I'm running this command:

`docker-machine create --driver hyperv --hyperv-virtual-switch "External" Test`

...and I'm getting this output:

```
Running pre-create checks...
Creating machine...
(Test) Copying C:\Users\Admin\.docker\machine\cache\boot2docker.iso to C:\Users\Admin\.docker\machine\machines\Test\boot2docker.iso...
(Test) Creating SSH key...
(Test) Creating VM...
(Test) Using switch "External"
(Test) Creating VHD
(Test) Starting VM...
Error creating machine: Error in driver during machine creation: exit status 1
```

This is on a Win10-1607 VM.

The error message appears to be rather generic. Nothing appears in the Event Logs for this, nor am I able to find any Docker log file that might indicate what the problem could be.

I've found other Q&As for the same error message, but they're all using the VirtualBox driver. This is Hyper-V. There's [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44393549/722393), but it remains unanswered.

How / where do I start researching what's causing this?

Answer (score 1):

Did you create a virtual switch (External) before trying to run the command? 
I think you must set up a new network switch using the virtual switch manager (in you case the name of the switch is External).

Comment: Yes, I tried it both with and without the switch (and corresponding reference in the command).

Comment: https://rominirani.com/docker-machine-windows-10-hyper-v-troubleshooting-tips-367c1ea73c24
This link can be useful to fix your problem

Comment: This looks very good, thank you! I'll have to go through it tomorrow, though—I've about had it for tonight. What a day... whew.